# Repetitive if statement into one clean if statement inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

Considering the case of having to check a billion conditions, how could I reduce an ugly, repetitive if statement into a clean, elegant if statement by using a for loop.

Here's an example of the monstrosity I'm talking about:

```
 if (
        x === 0 && y === 1 ||
        x === 2 && y === 3 ||
        x === 4 && y === 5 ||
        x === 6 && y === 7 ||
        x === 8 && y === 9
      ) {
        // do somethig...
      }
```

Comment: So you add a test fo x is even  and y is odd and their difference is one

Comment: Don't need the odd test. If the difference is 1 then it must be odd.

Comment: `x % 2 == 0 && y == x + 1`

Comment: Whenever you have a problem like this, look for obvious patterns like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the comments are right and there's a simple pattern to your tests (like even-x, odd-y), then just write that pattern into your test.  But if not, I would expect something like this to handle a more general case.  You can now add as many matching conditions as you like in a declarative fashion.

```js
const matches = [
  [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5],
  [6, 7], [8, 9], /* ... */
]

if (matches .some (([a, b]) => x == a && y == b)) {
   // ...
}
```

[`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) can be used to replace a collection like this joined by `||`.  If you wanted to join by `&&`, then you could use  [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

And of course your internal test (here `x == a && y == b`) can be anything you want.

While you *could* do something like this with a `for`-loop, I would expect it to be much less expressive and to be more verbose.  I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to reduce this if won't be some Javascript syntax trickery, but some math. In all your conditions, `y` is equal to `x+1` and `x` is an even number between `0` and `8`. In the general form, if `x` is restricted between some minimum and maximum, you could say that:

```js
minx = 0;
maxx = 8;
if (y === x + 1 &&
    x >= minx &&
    x <= maxx &&
    x % 2 === 0) {
    // some code...
}
```